# How to upload an image in img tag to a different server as a file or formData but not base64

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask

Basically, there are a lot of images on the website. The user selects one image by clicking on it and it's uploaded to a different server.

I have an implementation which reads the user selected image src in img tag and uploads it to a different server as a base64 string attached to the end of URL via ajax.

I want this image to be uploaded as formData or file upload. Any help?

My current implementation creates formData using the output of file reader and uploads it as data in ajax:

```
var img_data = new FormData();
// img is output of file reader which looks like "data:image/jpg;base64,XXX"
img_data.append("image", img, "site_image.jpg");

$.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url : "other server url",
    data : img_data,
    contentType: "image/jpeg",
    processData: false,
...}),
```

But I couldn't see any useful data in my flask server. Here's output in flask:

```
files: len: 0 type: <class 'werkzeug.datastructures.ImmutableMultiDict'>
[]
data: len: 136 type: <type 'str'>
------WebKitFormBoundaryJ8YC9pZxjqRl0tyD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"


------WebKitFormBoundaryJ8YC9pZxjqRl0tyD--

form: len: 0 type: <class 'werkzeug.datastructures.ImmutableMultiDict'>
ImmutableMultiDict([])
```

Got weird stuff in data str but couldn't get any image data.

Comment: What happens if you `console.log(img_data)`?

Comment: You should convert the base64 formatted img to a javascript file object than append it to form data. Check this; 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript

Comment: Why do you use the **output** of FileReader? Use directly the **input** Blob you passed in. Also, you should set your `contentType` to false, it will be sent as a FormData request, which will old your binary file, but not as an `image/jpeg` directly. I think the only way to do an `image/jpeg` request directly would be through a PUT request.

Comment: img_data is showing an empty dict `FormData {}` though `console.log(img)` shows image data. I don't understand!

Comment: @Kaiido I'm new to javascript so I did it that way. What do you mean by input blob? I have a function `toDataURL` which takes local image src like `abc/img.jpg` and returns data url which looks like `data:image/jpg;base64,XXX `. 

What would you suggest me to do? Yeah I'll modify `contentType`.

Comment: Where does this `toDataURL` function comes from? I though you talked about a [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) in your comment `// img is output of file reader`, if this is the case, then FileReader needs a Blob as input, so use this Blob directly instead of the useless dataURI. And if your `toDataURL` function really loads an image from url, then why don't you send the original url instead? You could still download the resource from the backend if you really need to.

Comment: Sorry about that. `toDataURL` is function name I've used, didn't know about builtin function. My `toDataURL` works as mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido, for now, I'm sending image URL from website to another server which downloads that image.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading images without converting to `base64` required you to use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

For me I use [`jQuery Form`](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/), It'll mimic ajax post for you and (do fallback if 
method not supported in browser).

If you want to do it manually, see this question and its best answer:
[How to use FormData for ajax file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that post. There they are taking the image from html input tag as `$('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]`. How can I do it in my case? As the images are already on website.